# creating a python binding of a function returning a pointer to a vector with boost

Tags: c++, containers, c++17, boost-python

I am a python native and recently started to investigate C++. To try to speed up some things I am trying to create python bindings for certain functions I wrote in C++ with the boost library. The code looks as following:

*tools.h*

```
#ifndef UEBUNG1_TOOLS_H
#define UEBUNG1_TOOLS_H

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/suite/indexing/vector_indexing_suite.hpp>

using namespace std;

vector<string> *product(string alphabet, int repeats);

vector<string> *product(vector<string> pools);

vector<string>* hammdist(string &pattern, int distance);

#endif //UEBUNG1_TOOLS_H
```

*tools.cpp*

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/python/suite/indexing/vector_indexing_suite.hpp>
#include "tools.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

vector<string> *product(string alphabet, int repeats) {
    //initializing vector
    auto *results = new vector<string>();
    for(auto character : alphabet) {
        string tmpstr;
        tmpstr = character;
        results->push_back(tmpstr);
    }

    //cartesian product generation
    for(int i = 1; i < repeats; i++) {
        vector<string> tmp = *results;
        results->clear();

        //iterating over temporary list adding elements from pool to each contained string
        for(auto &it : tmp) {
            for(auto &character : alphabet) {
                results->push_back(it + character);
            }
        }
    }
    return results;
}

vector<string> product(vector<string> pools) {
    //initializing vector
    auto *results = new vector<string>();
    for(auto character : pools[0]) {
        string tmpstr;
        tmpstr = character;
        results->push_back(tmpstr);
    }

    //removing the first pool container
    pools.erase(pools.begin());

    //cartesian product generation
    for(const auto &pool : pools) {
        vector<string> tmp = *results;
        results->clear();

        //iterating over temporary list adding elements from pool to each contained string
        for(auto &it : tmp) {
            for(auto character : pool) {
                results->push_back(it + character);
            }
        }
    }
    return results;
}


vector<string>* hammdist(string &pattern, int distance) {
    map<char, string> possibles = {
            {'A', "CGT"},
            {'C', "AGT"},
            {'G', "ACT"},
            {'T', "ACG"}
    };
    auto *results = new vector<string>();
    vector<string> *masks = product("01", pattern.size());
    for(auto &mask : *masks) {
        auto *permute = new vector<string>();
        auto *tmp = new vector<string>();
        if(count(mask.begin(), mask.end(), '1') == distance) {
            for(int i = 0; i < pattern.size(); i++) {
                if(mask[i] != '1') {
                    string tmpstr;
                    tmpstr = pattern[i];
                    tmp->push_back(tmpstr);
                }
                else {
                    tmp->push_back(possibles[pattern[i]]);
                }
            }
            permute = product(*tmp);
            results->insert(results->end(), permute->begin(), permute->end());
        }
        delete permute;
        delete tmp;
    }
    return results;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(tools) {
    def("hammdist", hammdist, return_value_policy<manage_new_object>());

    class_<vector<string>>("string_vector").def(vector_indexing_suite<vector<string>>());
}
```

The `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(tools)` invocation with all its containing function calls was mainly compiled using these sources:

- [does boost python support a function returning a vector, by ref or value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240971/does-boost-python-support-a-function-returning-a-vector-by-ref-or-value)
- https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/python/doc/html/reference/topics/indexing_support.html#topics.indexing_support.index_suite_sub_classes.vector_index_suite
- https://wiki.python.org/moin/boost.python

But trying to compile this code using CLion which invokes clang and cmake always gives a Linker error:

> vtable for boost::python::objects::py_function_impl_base", referenced
>   from:
>
> boost::python::objects::py_function_impl_base::py_function_impl_base()
>   in tools.cpp.o
>
> NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual
>   member function has no definition.
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

The CMakeLists.txt file looks as following:

*CMakeLists.txt*

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(Uebung1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

if(APPLE)
    set(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX ".so")
endif(APPLE)

find_package(PythonLibs 2.7 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR src/)
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})

set(BOOST_ROOT "/Users/DaniBook/miniconda3/pkgs/boost-1.66.0-py27_1")
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR "/Users/DaniBook/miniconda3/pkgs/boost-1.66.0-27_1/lib")

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS python REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_library(tools SHARED src/tools.cpp src/tools.h)
target_link_libraries(tools ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
set_target_properties(tools PROPERTIES PREFIX "")
add_executable(Uebung1 src/main.cpp src/tools.h src/tools.cpp)
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include <iostream>
#include "tools.h"
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    string pattern = "AAAAAAAGGGGGG";

    auto *results = hammdist(pattern, 4);

    int i = 1;
    for(auto &res : *results) {
        cout << res << i << endl;
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I really don´t know what I am doing wrong and I was not able to find any working example of what I am trying to accomplish on the internet. Can sombody tell me what the problem is?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to build the interface by making the following changes to the code:

*tools.cpp*

```
/* 
   initializing function pointers in order to tell boost that we have 
   overloaded functions to expose to python
*/
vector<string> *(*product1)(string, int) = &product;
vector<string> *(*product2)(vector<string> pools) = &product;

//include all functions that are used by the function to expose to the BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE call

using namespace boost::python;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(tools) {
    //telling boost_python that we have overloaded functions which need to be called in the respective situations
    //return_value_policy<manage_new_objects> is required in order for the interface to handle the new invocation and the returned pointer

    def("product", product1, return_value_policy<manage_new_object>());
    def("product", product2, return_value_policy<manage_new_object>());

    def("hammdist", hammdist, return_value_policy<manage_new_object>());

    //vector_indexing_suite handles the wrapping of vector member functions
    //enables handling vector in a pythonic way when using in python

    class_<std::vector<string>>("string_vector")
        .def(vector_indexing_suite<std::vector<string>>());
```

}

renaming the project and setting the target to the desired .cpp only while removing the add_executable directive enables an error-free build.

*CMakeLists.txt*

```
make_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(tools)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

if(APPLE)
    set(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX ".so")
endif(APPLE)

find_package(PythonLibs 2.7 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR src/)
include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})

set(BOOST_ROOT "/Users/DaniBook/miniconda3/pkgs/boost-1.66.0-py27_1")
set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR "/Users/DaniBook/miniconda3/pkgs/boost-1.66.0-27_1/lib")

find_package(Boost COMPONENTS python REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_library(tools SHARED src/tools.cpp src/tools.h)
target_link_libraries(tools ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
set_target_properties(tools PROPERTIES PREFIX "")
```

The above changes build the project without an error, however the created tools.so interface can not be imported